# Неправильно выполняется password_verify

Tags: php, база-данных, redbeanphp

Код такой:

```
$user = R::find('user', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
    if ($user) {
        if(password_verify($data['password'], $user->password)) {
            echo 'ok';
        }
        else {
            echo = 'Данные введены неверно';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo = 'Пользователь не найден';
    }
```

Он проверяет введёный логин и если аккаунт существует он проверяет пароль, а если верный и пароль то выводит "ok". Я создал в базе данных аккаунт с ником `admin` и паролем `123`. Так вот пользователя он находит, но говорит что пароль введён не верно (выполняется 1-ый по счёту `else`).

Почему он видит логин, но не видит пароль? Что не так?(

Comment: Вы используете функцию password_hash для хэширования пароля?

Comment: Нет, не использую

Comment: Как это сделать в моем случае?

Comment: Эти функции работают в связке. Нужно хранить в базе данных хэш, сгенерированный функцией password_hash. А для проверки подавать в password_verify пароль, введённый пользователем, и этот хэш из базы данных.

Comment: Получается password_hash($user->password); или что?

Comment: Вот пример из документации http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php#121974

Comment: Я всё равно не понимаю как мне в password_hash поместить $user->password

Comment: НЕ НУЖНО помещать  в password_hash поместить $user->password. Надо в базу данных записывать не 123, а хэш

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать функции [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php) и [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php) в связке. Когда пользователь при регистрации задаёт пароль вы должны сгенерировать на его основе хэш:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Этот хэш вместе с логином нужно нужно занести в базу данных. Заметьте, что нельзя хранить пароль в открытом виде, т.к. это небезопасно. Поэтому мы используем [хэширование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) пароля.

Когда пользователь при входе вводит логин и пароль, мы должны выбрать в базе данных запись, соответствующую введённому логину (если она есть). После этого мы проверяем? соответствует ли пароль хэшу, хранящемуся в базе данных:

```
if(password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // Верный пароль
} else {
    // Неверный пароль
}
```

Comment: я не понимаю как занести redbeanphp элемент в хеш, там же не какое-то конкретное значение, а user->password (пароль из бд)

Comment: @newArray, так вы брали пример из https://gist.github.com/kirwebpr/b3d820f44b7de3a8bfe22d6c7119f62a? Там ведь всё есть. В signup.php используется password_hash.